# Parallel Port inter-computer communication possibility

Tags: c, device, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have browsed through the links and the topics suggested here, before posting this, still not clear, so posting on.

My question; is it possible to communicate between two parallel ports of computers with a straight cable and not a [Laplink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable) cable?

As I have seen, 
http://pinouts.ru/ParallelPorts/ParallelPC_pinout.shtml
http://www.beyondlogic.org/spp/parallel.html
http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ih/doc/par/

I infer from these links, pin 10 (nAck) that is connected to Status Register (bit6) and Pin 11 (Busy) will be acting in INPUT DIRECTION on both computers, which would not let the communication cycle to complete.

Is this correct? Can we have a way for the straight (1 to 1) cable to communicate or not?

Comment: Maybe a question for super-user?  But on the other hand, to pull this off, you would have to know register level stuff.

Comment: I would not be surprised if this could be made to work, if both computers support [bi-directional][1] data transfer.




  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284  But you would have to write software yourself. I also don't know if you could fry anything with a straight cable.

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for not answering your question directly but. As far as I remember it should be possible to communicate between two computers using a straight parallell cable but to be honest I am not 100% sure. Note that there are variations of the parallell.
Also if you have intentions of programming something yourself you can on the Windows platform use inpoup32 library to make the task a bit more easy.

Comment: http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH21/CH21-3.html#HEADING3-1  Any comments on this info?? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did not read all but according to this a straight 1-1 cable is no good. You have to cross the wires for it to work. I would suggest you get a tested and proven cable for this ;) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can write proper drivers/application which can communicate through the parallel port pins then it could be possible. My guess that that an asynchronous communication is highly possible, which can be done like a computer sends data to a device with parallel port. Turn by turn the computers would become the master device (half duplex) and use the link to send byte at a time.

Comment: Used this link http://people.redhat.com/twaugh/parport/html/x916.html to communicate between parallel ports of two systems. Unsuccessful in receiving an Interrupt at read end. Connected two parallel ports using straight cable (system-printer). Found this link which denies for usage of the cable. http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH21/CH21-3.html#HEADING3-1  Please throw some light on it.

Comment: never tried, so cannot tell for sure. you can have a look at this: [http://www.tecno.demon.co.uk/dcc/dcc.html](http://www.tecno.demon.co.uk/dcc/dcc.html) also check the directory:
[http://www.tecno.demon.co.uk/dcc/](http://www.tecno.demon.co.uk/dcc/)
Please let us know what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander can connect to another PC via LPT cable. The other side needs to have either LPTDOS server software or another Total Commander. It was quite reliable, but I can not recall if it was based on a Laplink cable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Inter computer communication through parallel port is possible through a laplink cable. nibble at a time with software handshaking for synchronization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Line_Internet_Protocol